# Tensor calculus - The properties of the Tensors

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, tensors, symmetric-matrices

We have a given a tensor $(2,0)$ and its components are, $M^{\alpha \beta} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 & 2 \\ 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & -2 & 0  \end{pmatrix}$

The questions ask us to find the components of

(i) $M^{\alpha}_{\beta}$

(ii)  $M^{\beta}_{\alpha}$

(iii) $M_{\alpha \beta}$

***Answers***

(i)

I used the $M^{\alpha}_{\beta} = \eta_{\beta \mu}M^{\alpha \mu}$ for $\eta_{\beta \mu} = diag(-1,1,1,1)$

If my calculations are corret I find $M^{\alpha}_{\beta} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & -2 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\ 0 & -2 & -1 & 0  \end{pmatrix}$

(ii)

Similarly I thought I can write

$M^{\beta}_{\alpha} = \eta_{\alpha \mu}M^{\beta \mu}$

(iii)

$M_{\alpha \beta} = \eta_{\alpha \gamma}\eta_{\beta \mu}M^{\gamma \mu}$

These can be calculated by using algebra but my question is, can we take a shortcut ?

***Questions***

**Q1)** Can we say that the $M^{\beta}_{\alpha} = (M^{\alpha}_{\beta})^T$ ?

**Q2)** Can we say that $M_{\alpha \beta} M^{\alpha \beta} = I$ Where I is the identity matrix?

**Q3)** For a given $(m,n)$ tensor can we **always** say that, the components of the $(m,n)$ tensor times the components of the $(n,m)$ tensor gives an identity matrix  (i.e $T^{\alpha \beta}_{\gamma}T^{\gamma} _{\alpha \beta} = I$)?

**Q4)** Similarly for a given $(n,n)$ matrix (i.e $T^{\beta \gamma}_{\alpha \mu}$) can we say that the transpose of the components  will **always** gives the components of the $T^{\alpha \mu}_{\beta \gamma}$

Comment: Your calculation for $M_\beta^\alpha$ isn't correct. It should be the same as $M^{\alpha \beta}$ but with the zeroth column being hit with minus signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

$1)$ No, since

$$M_\beta^\alpha = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & -1 & 0 & 2 \\ -2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & -2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$M_\alpha^\beta = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 & 2 \\ 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & -2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

These don't look like transposes to me.

$2)$ No, since the quantity you describe contracts all of the indices, there is no way it could be anything other than a scalar.

$3)$ No, for the same reason as $2$

$4)$ No, for the same reason as $1$

Comment: If you wish, depending on the convention, each application of the metric tensor also does a "transpose", but this is silly for a variety of reasons. One, you gain an ambiguity as to which index refers to the columns or the rows. Two, matrices are only type $(1,1)$ tensors in the first place. Arranging the other rank $2$ tensor types in an array of information does not make it grammatically correct to apply matrix operations to them.

Comment: I understand it thanks